# How to use an image as a button in GTK?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

How to use an image as a button in GTK in c language in code blocks? I have tried making the button of same color as that of the background and then adding image on it. But there is a outline or shadow still there. So, how can i remove those shadows or is there a way to directly use an image as a button?

Comment: You may probably need to just put the image and [handle its button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566721/detect-click-on-gtkimage) in the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is outlined by [@Shabhaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482302/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-button-in-gtk/22485707#comment34200585_22482302), by putting the image in an `EventBox`, and handling the button-press event.

The other way is by placing the image in the button and customizing the style of the button to remove the outline and the shadow. You would call `gtk_rc_parse_string()` to define an outline-less button class, and `gtk_widget_set_name()` on your button to apply the style.